# Travelling to the future while seemingly standing still?

Tags: general-relativity, time, time-dilation, time-travel

Some time ago I thought about this possibility, knowing about the time dilation from general relativity. What would theoretically happen if I travelled at near the speed of light in a circle that has such a small radius so that my brain and the people around me wouldn't notice I am moving at all? If possible, that could allow someone to travel to the future by seemingly not moving at all. I hope the question is clear and please let me know if it isn't, so that I can later fix it and make it more comprehensive.

Comment: Yes, the time dilation factor works even if you're just going in a circle. But the required accelerations would be very painful.

Answer (score 3):

That's funny, I had the exact same thought while I was first taught special relativity. This can definitely work, though you would require enormous amounts of energy. An example would be a satellite in orbit around Earth. Given high enough speed, the people inside the satellite could undergo significant time dilation(everyone who is moving undergoes time-dilation).

Also from @knzhou comment. You would require a large enough radius so as to avoid tense forces on people that are in orbit(that's why the satellite would be more appropriate).